# Measure distance walked with GeoPoint and displaying distance to user

Tags: android, gps, distance, geopoints

In my app I am trying to make it possible to calculate the distance a person walks. To do this I have created a LocationHelper class that should get me the current GeoPoint every 30 seconds or 10 meters. I already have a method that returns the distance in meters between two GeoPoints that I know works, because I have used it in a previous project. I also have an Activity called WalkActivity where I call the method getDistance() in LocationHelper and display it in a TextView that is updated every 30 seconds with help of a timer. See code below.

When I run my app nothing is displayed. It says "You have walked 0.0 meters" no matter how far I walk. I get no error messages. What do you think I am doing wrong? I have searched and looked at numerous examples but found none that can tell me what is wrong here.

I hope this is not a stupid question, any help is welcome :)

```
package Controller;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * Location Helper Class that handles creation of the Location Manager and Location Listener.
 * 
 */
public class LocationHelper{

    private double distance = 0;
    GeoPoint geoPointA;
    GeoPoint geoPointB;

    //location manager and listener
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private MyLocationListener locationListener;

    /**
     * Constructor for LocationHelper
     * 
     * @param context - The context of the calling activity.
     */
    public LocationHelper(Context context){

        //setup the location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //create the location listener
        locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

        //setup a callback for when the GPS gets a lock and we receive data
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 10, locationListener);

    }

    /**
     * Receiving notifications from the Location Manager when they are sent.
     *
     */
    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {


        /**
         * called when the location service reports a change in location
         */
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            if (geoPointB == null){
                geoPointB = new GeoPoint((int) location.getLatitude(), (int) location.getLongitude());
            }

            //Getting the current GeoPoint.
            geoPointA = new GeoPoint((int) location.getLatitude(), (int) location.getLongitude());

            //Calculating the distance in meters
            distance = distance + nu.placebo.whatsup.util.Geodetics.distance(geoPointA, geoPointB);

            //Making current GeoPoint the previous GeoPoint
            geoPointB = geoPointA;

        }

        //called when the provider is disabled
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        //called when the provider is enabled
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        //called when the provider changes state
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    }

    /**
     * Stop updates from the Location Service.
     */
    public void killLocationServices(){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    }

    /**
     * Get Distance 
     *
     * @return - The current distance walked.
     */
    public double getDistance(){
        return distance;
    }

    /**
     * Check if a location has been found yet.
     * @return - True if a location has been acquired. False otherwise.
     */
    public Boolean gpsEnabled(){
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }   
}

package edu.chl.dat255.sofiase.readyforapet;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import Controller.LocationHelper;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WalkActivity extends Activity{

    private TextView displayDistance;
    private int delay = 0;
    private int period = 30000;
    private Timer timer;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    private LocationHelper location;

    /**
     * On Create method
     * 
     * @param savedInstanceState - bundle
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.walkactivity);
        location = new LocationHelper(this);

        //Checking if the GPS is enabled, else let the user start GPS if wanted.
        if (location.gpsEnabled()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is Enabled on your devide", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            showGPSDisabledAlert();
        }

        Button startWalking = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startwalking);
        startWalking.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            /**
             * Method onClick for the start walking button
             * 
             * @param v - View
             */
            public void onClick (View v){

                try{
                    timer = new Timer();
                    timer.schedule(myTimerTask, delay, period);
                } 
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

                );

        Button stopWalking = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopwalking);
        stopWalking.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            /**
             * Method onClick for the stop walking button
             * 
             * @param v - View
             */
            public void onClick (View v){
                timer.cancel();
                location.killLocationServices();
                startActivity(new Intent(WalkActivity.this, PetActivity.class));
            }
        }
                );

    }


    TimerTask myTimerTask = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    displayDistance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance);
                    displayDistance.setText("You have walked " + location.getDistance() + " meters so far.");
                }
            });

        }

    };

    /**
     * If GPS is turned off, lets the user either choose to enable GPS or cancel.
     * 
     */
    private void showGPSDisabledAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("GPS is disabled on your device. Would you like to enable it?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Go to Settings Page To Enable GPS",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
            }
        });
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem in your code is when you create a `GeoPoint` from a `Location` in `onLocationChanged(Location location)`.  Both `getLatitude()` and `getLongitude()` from the class `Location` return degrees, but the constructor for `GeoPoint` takes microdegrees.  This might be screwing up your distance calculation because your `GeoPoint` coordinates could be, let's just say, 42 degrees, which turns out to be .0000042 degrees in the `GeoPoint`.

Also, you might try printing the current location somehow, through the debug monitor or through a `Toast` message.  This will greatly help in the debugging process, as you can see your Lat/Long changing and debug from there.

Note:  I would recommend updating to Maps v2, they changed a lot of classes and added `LatLng` which makes things easier to understand :)

Comment: Oh, thanks for your help!
I multiplied getLatitude() with (deg * 1E6) and now, after walking about 50 meters and waiting 1 minute i got "You have walked 6520332.95... meters so far". So this feels like an improvement, but obviously something is still wrong! I will take your advice and try to find out how to print the current location somehow!

Comment: Glad it's working!  Be sure to let me know if it all works out!

Comment: Oh no, my bad! I forgot to multiply one of the variables. It works now! Great, thanks!