# Measure distance walked in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to make a mobile app that can calculate the distance covered by the user (with meter as the `unitSystem`). The app have to calculate in real time the distance covered and save The user’s latitude and longitude, and update them (without erasing them) each 3 meters covered.

Apparently, Google Maps API offers tools to do so, but i can't find the exact way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [The Google Maps Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) to provide the travel distance and time for a matrix of origins and destinations. The information returned is based on the recommended route between start and end points, as calculated by the Google Maps API, and consists of rows containing duration and distance values for each pair.

You can use [Geocoding Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) that converts addresses into geographic coordinates to get the user's longitude and latitude.

You can refer in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650929/measure-distance-walked-with-geopoint-and-displaying-distance-to-user) on how to calculate the distance a person walked. Here is also an [example](https://github.com/xd6/GoogleMapDistanceMeasure) on how to calculate the distance between 2 or more points.

Answer (score 0):

I think the road API is much better:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/overview